# .BAT keeps on closing when ever an answer is entered

Tags: batch-file

I'm working on this .BAT project for my script class, and Im stuck on this one issue when ever I've entered an answer such as rock or paper the bat file closes. I have even ask my professor on this issue as well but hes working on it to find a solution. I would like to find that solution first, if possible.

I have also made a github link so you can see the whole script
https://github.com/CyborgVillager/Rock-Paper-Scissors/issues/1

This project name is called rps.bat, Im not sure if that will ring any bells just in case any of you guys have done this before haha. Anyhow Ill be trying to find a solution to this, in the mean time your help will be greatly appreciated !

```
 REM Ask the player to make their choice
    SET /p answer= Type either rock, paper, or scissors:

    GOTO :EOF

    REM This procedure randomly determines the computer's choice

    :GetComputerChoice

    REM Get a random Number
```

Comment: if I copy/paste and run your GitHub code I get errors when I answer the question. `The system cannot find the batch label specified - Continue` and `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

Comment: Also found this... `GOTO :Continue` but you declared this `:Contunue`. Obviously... `:Contunue` != `:Continue`

Comment: Regarding the snippet from the question (just noticed the same thing on _GitHub_): after your `SET /p` command (which reads user input and stores it in `answer`), you have `GOTO :EOF` which is something similar to _end of program_, so it's behaving as you instructed it.

Comment: With the continue label fixed, and `GOTO :EOF` changed to `GOTO :MyEnding`, and after adding a `:MyEnding` at the end of the file... I can see your programs does not reach `CheckForInvalid`

Comment: `GOTO :EOF` means "go to the end of the file"... so existing after your `set /p` is correct

Comment: Do not put a space between your variable name and the equals symbol in your `SET` commands.

Comment: Probably a good suggestion but that will have no impact.

Comment: @MatthewWhited, who are you directing your last comment to?

Comment: You, the space after the equal is dropped.

Comment: Thank you guys, you all are awesome! I'm currently fixing the errors for this .bat file . I'm literally energized in learning more about programming languages and this is a major stepping stone for me in that process. Anyhow I wish you all a good morning and keep on coding mates ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GOTO :EOF` is a special command.  It will goto the end of the file so your code is working "correctly".

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490914.aspx

Comment: I don't see it given as an example, but `GOTO :LabelName` works as well (maybe because _extensions_ are enabled by default?).

Comment: Either way `GOTO :EOF` is End of File... it will exit right away.

Answer (score 0):

2 things... in the end... Changing `GOTO :EOF` to `GOTO :MyEnding` has no impact so I'll leave that out...

I found 2 issues with your code.

One... you declared `:Contunue` as a label, but you are doing `GOTO :Continue`. Since `:Contunue` != `:Continue` that's a problem.

Then there is this one...
This portion of your code, in the label `CompareChoices`, is missing a `)`

```
IF /I %answer% == rock (
IF %CardImage% == rock (
SET results="You Tie"
SET /a NoTies = NoTies +1
)
```

By the looks of how you wrapped the other `if` statements below that one... I'm guessing the missing `)` goes here

From this

```
IF /I %answer% == rock (
IF %CardImage% == rock (
SET results="You Tie"
SET /a NoTies = NoTies +1
)

IF %CardImage% == scissors (
SET results ="You Win"
SET /a NOWins = NoWins +1
)

IF %CardImage% == paper (
SET results ="You Lose"
SET /a NOLosses = NoLosses +1
)
```

To this. Added the `)` on the very last line.

```
IF /I %answer% == rock (
IF %CardImage% == rock (
SET results="You Tie"
SET /a NoTies = NoTies +1
)

IF %CardImage% == scissors (
SET results ="You Win"
SET /a NOWins = NoWins +1
)

IF %CardImage% == paper (
SET results ="You Lose"
SET /a NOLosses = NoLosses +1
))
```

After all that... the game results are wrong, but at least the program is running. Up to you to figure out the results ;) Or ask a new question for it?

Fixing the label name fixes this error `The system cannot find the batch label specified - Continue`, while fixing the missing `)` fixes the `The syntax of the command is incorrect`.

Word of advice... If you are actively working on a bat file, and troubleshooting it... Don't double click the file. Instead, run CMD, and then run your bat file from within it. The difference is that when running from an existing CMD instance, instead of double clicking, the CMD prompt will stay on screen when the program is done running. Thus, allowing you to review what went on if you were to scroll up.

When you double click the Bat file, the CMD prompt just goes away as soon as the program is done running(unless you have a pause or timeout at the end of your script).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! This really helps a lot haha, and thank to everybody else that join in to help as well!